# Cartoon/anime about a giant robotic fish in the sky

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

I remember seeing this at least 15 years ago. Don’t know if it was anime or cartoon.

It had islands that float in the sky. Starts when this kid's island is eaten by a giant robotic fish that swims in the sky. He is rescued by a big airship that is trying to destroy the fish piloted by an older man and his daughter or granddaughter. At first they fly around in wing suits but at the end of the movie they create an airplane to fight the fish.

The name *Sky Soldiers* sticks in my head but I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oiX-qsT7UuI

Comment: It is not Castle in the Sky nor Skyland

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*Aero Troopers* (2003)?

From the jacket below, which features a robotic-looking fish (and what do you know, it's got Mark Hamill in it!):

> In a world beyond imagination where fantastic tree villages float in mid air, a young boy named Joshua dreams of adventure. Forced from his home by an evil mechanical beast called Nemeclous, he discovers a fantastic world high above the clouds. There he must join an elite force - the Aero-troopers - who are sworn to protect the skies. Joshua now finds himself on the kind of adventure he has always dreamed about... but little does he know the entire fate of the skies lies in his hands.

[image: DVD jacket with blue robotic fish]

The follwing demo video contains various clips from the movie, including some wingsuits at 3'25. A comment by the poster (who apparently worked on the movie) explains it was made with the [3ds Max](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autodesk_3ds_Max) animation software.

---

Found with the Google query `anime "floating islands" "robotic fish"` which returned [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/1nyuk3/help_with_movie_title/) on which someone (you?) commented:

> I have been searching for this same anime. they end up fighting a big robotic fish that eats the floating islands. I cannt find it anywhere, and I thought the title was "aero soldiers".

*Aero Soldiers* + *Sky Soldiers* + a Thesaurus lead me to Googling "aero troopers" on an off chance, and jackpot.

Comment: Hahah yeah I posted that a while ago. I have no idea why I never tried troopers instead of soldiers. Although I remember it being more cartoony not so much crappy cgi.  Four years of searching and all I needed was a thesaurus

Comment: @Frenchie at least the mystery is solved now :) well, the above was only a demo, maybe they improved the quality once they released it. Although from the very few clips I can find online (I couldn't even locate a copy of the movie), it looks more like a PS2 game than a cartoon, granted! As for you remembering it like a cartoon - the name "Frenchie" + floating islands + cartoon: any chance [_Chasseurs de Dragons_](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0944834/?ref_=nv_sr_2) rings a bell?

Comment: Oh, the chutzpah of referring to "Star Wars, Treasure Planet and The Iron Giant"...

Comment: @zovits If you mashed all three together you'd wind up with a 50ft tall Long John Silver with terrible asthma and a giant laser sword

Comment: @Machavity I'd watch that.

Comment: Those characters are on the wrong side of uncanny valley....